# Word-Addin heading detection

Tags: detection, word-addins, heading

I need to detect the heading in a Word document (using the JavaScript API). This is easy if the document actually contains headings, i.e. paragraphs with style "heading*". But for my application I can't guarantee that headings are set. They might be only optical heading with larger font etc. For this reason Word provides the [feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-detected-headings-in-navigation-pane-f17c0ae0-d2dc-4633-8f38-8cdce7452c42?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to also automatically detect headings based on the styling.
Does anyone know how or if it is possible to access these detected headings programmatically? Doing this detection myself seems tedious.

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
        const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
        context.load(paragraphs, 'text, style');

        await context.sync();

        paragraphs.items.forEach(paragraph => {
            if (["heading"].some(style => paragraph.style.startsWith(style))) {
                headings.push(paragraph.text);
            }
        });

        await context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandler);
```

This is the code for getting the already set headings. I want something similar for the detected ones.